# Adding extra keys to $wp global array in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it good practice in Wordpress to add extra keys to the global array $wp (or any global variable in Wordpress for that matter).

I need to access my theme options in all the files in Wordpress but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Something like:

```
$wp['theme-options] = $theme_options;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'all files in Wordpress'?  If you're talking about passing variables from your functions/plugin into a template file, those are stored within the global $wp_query object.  You can use the get() and set() methods -

```
function my_plugin(){
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set( 'foo', 'bar' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'plugin' );           // happens early in the logic

function my_plugin_two(){
    global $wp_query;
    $foo = $wp_query->get( 'foo' );
    var_dump( $foo == 'bar' );            // TRUE
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'plugin' );  // happens later
```

Then in your template file, you will have $foo all ready to go.

```
// don't need to reference $wp_query,
// load_template() in wp-includes/template.php has set up the variable for you
get_header();
echo $foo; 
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to create more global variables than needed.

Take a look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)